# Linking stdlibs with Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.mac, xamarin-linker

I have created a simple binding project with Xamarin. The binding project imports a static library `MyLibrary.a`. It also contains `ApiDefinition.cs` and `StructAndEnum.cs` made through sharpie tool.

Now I have an iOS project that links that binding project. `MyLibrary.a` in order to work needs some frameworks and libs (see below).

[image]

In order to make it working, I followed the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/).

In the iOS project, I added the following `mtouch arguments` (see also attached imaged).

> --cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security
> -framework AVFoundation -libicucore -libxml2 -libc++ -libzd -libstdc++.6.0.9"

[image]

When I try to compile I always end with a build error.

> MTOUCH: error MT5209: Native linking error: library not found for
> -libicucore MTOUCH: error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc:
> -L/Users/tmp/Documents/Projects/Ovp/BindinTest.iOS -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices
> -framework Security -framework AVFoundation -libicucore -libxml2 -libc++ -libzd -libstdc++.6.0.9 MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Any clue to make it work? Maybe something is missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -libicucore -libxml2 -libc++ -libzd -libstdc++.6.0.9

This is not how you pass library options for gcc linkage.

To link a static or dynamic library `libicucore.<extension>`
that resides in `/path/to/the/lib`, the commandline options are:

```
-L/path/to/the/lib -licucore
```

Note that the `lib` prefix of the library name is ommitted in
the `-l` option: the linker assumes it. And if `/path/to/the/lib` is one of the linker's 
default search directories for libraries then you can omit it. If you have
another look at your Xamarin documentation you will see that `libMyLibrary.a`
is linked with the option `-lMyLibrary`.

Some other things about these linkage options seem very odd to my GCC eyes,
but as I know next to nothing about iOS development I won't anticipate
problems that you haven't had yet.

Comment: Mike, yes it's my `-libicucore` is not correct. icucore is a stdlib, So, do I need to specify it as `-L/path/to/the/lib -licucore`? Thanks you.

Comment: It's not a standard GCC library, but I believe its "standard" for iOS, so
I can't say if it will be found by default however your GCC toolchain is
adapted for iOS. Try with no `-L<path>` for it and see. If the library
is reported not found then you'll need to discover where it resides and
add an `-L` to it.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Can you suggest me a good intro on GCC and gcc_flags?

Comment: [This](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) is as good a starter as I know, but ultimately rely on the [offical documentation for your version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), e.g. [the commandline options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/index.html#toc_Invoking-GCC)
`gcc_flags` is not a GCC keyword or option: I guess it is an Xamarin keyword used for passing options to GCC.